What does it mean by "elaborate" for material components in spellcasting?
I am viewing the core rules of 3.5 (in SRD) and found a description like this:

Unless these materials are elaborate preparing these materials is a free action.

I wonder what it means by "elaborate" here. Is there any spell would take more than a free action for preparing the materials, or is it totally depending on DM's decision?
Possible Example: Sunburst

Arcane Material Component: A piece of sunstone and a naked flame.

It's probably not a good idea to "take" a flame out of a pouch directly, since a candle can be easily extinguished by a small wind. (I also wonder if I can put a burning candle in a pouch and drag it out without hurting my hand. Sounds like this pouch is some sorts of bag of holding.)
Another possible example: Magic Circle Against Evil

Arcane Material Component: A little powdered silver with which you trace a 3-foot diameter circle on the
floor (or ground) around the creature to be warded.

Since you need to "trace" it around a 3-foot (1-meter) diameter circle, you probably won't be able to do that correctly with just a single standard action without some magical help.

The full version of that rule is

Unless these materials are elaborate, such as the the 2-foot-by-4-boot [sic] mirror that a wizard needs to cast scrying, preparing these materials is a free action.

(Player’s Handbook, pg. 140)
Scrying makes no particular mention of being elaborate, nor does the full version of the rule particularly offer any hard-and-fast rule for determining that it is. Scrying does have an hour-long casting time, so the non-free-action manipulation of the material component is a non-issue for that spell, but that doesn’t really help us.
In short, “elaborate” seems to be left entirely up to the DM’s judgment, with nothing to go on but their own subjective opinion, nor any guidance on exactly what it should take if it’s not a free action. But the rule exists, apparently as an invitation to DMs to insert their opinion where they see fit. On the one hand, this is nothing that Rule 0 didn’t already invite the DM to do. On the other, I think this is a very poor place for the DM to insert their opinion, so it disappoints me that the authors invite the DM to do so. I recommend DMs exercise their right to simply not—material components don’t deserve the conceptual or textual space they already consume, much less more. For something like scrying, where the casting time is an hour anyway, it’s fine, but in combat that kind of thing is problematic.
(The problem, by the way, is with it not being indicated to players: it’s either an immersion-breaking gotcha moment (a spellcaster would know this about their own spells) or a big delay of game as the player goes “oh wait, I wouldn’t have prepared that if I knew that, so let me pick something else...” If you want to go through all the spells and pick out which ones you think have “elaborate” material components ahead of time, that would be acceptable. You do have to be careful about exactly what you require, though.)
Anyway, the rule also covers a few explicit examples, like the optional evil components in Book of Vile Darkness, or the snow for Snowcasting in Frostburn. Whether or not the author was anticipating these kinds of specific examples or not, it does work out. As addressed in the parenthetical above, material components specifically noted as elaborate aren’t nearly as problematic for the game. (Note how rarely those things actually get used, though, for the risks associated with even properly-indicated “elaborate” material components.)
